# Calling background Service from an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have an Activity and a background Service. I start the Service via Intent from the Activity. The Service runs indefinitely even if the Activity is closed. But the problem here is if I clear the memory from the Task manager the Service stops and is not started again untill the Activity is launched again. I want the Service to start automatically after some time the memory is cleared. How could I achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule running your service.

In your main (root) activity:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(
        Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    service.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
        REPEAT_TIME, pending);
}
```

This will start service in 30 seconds after your activity has been stopped.
Alternatively you can define BroadcastReceiver which will check if service is running and start it. To achieve this, just create broadcast `PendingIntent`.

More code and examples you can find in [Android Service Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#ownservice).

Comment: I followed the tutorial you mentioned. But the service doesn't starts automatically when the RAM memory is cleared.

Comment: Your example starts the Service and makes it run indifinetly even after the Activity is closed. But after the RAM memory is cleared the Service is never started automatically untill the Activity is launched. I have an idea, please tell me if this can be followed. Service should be written as a different application which can be started via BroadcastReceiver. The Service and Activity shares a local database. So a ContentProvider should be created to share the database between both the applications. Is this possible?

Comment: With my example service will start even when application is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

```
AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),30000, pending);
```

this code is true 30000 miliseconds run backgroundService